# Differential of a particular function

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, optimization, numerical-methods

Given two $PQR$ and $P'Q'R'$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I want to find a bijection $f$ between $PQR$ and $P'Q'R'$ such that:

1) $\widetilde{M}:=sup_{x\in PQR}sup_{||v||=1}||dfv||=$ max$\{\frac{P'Q'}{PQ},\frac{P'R'}{PR},\frac{Q'R'}{QR}\}=:M$

2) $\widetilde{m}:=inf_{x\in PQR}inf_{||v||=1}||dfv||=$ min$\{\frac{P'Q'}{PQ},\frac{P'R'}{PR},\frac{Q'R'}{QR}\}=:m$"

Does this bijection always exist?

Comment: Implicit in your notation $||dfv||$ is an assumption that $f$ is, let's say, $C^1$. Would you be happy with something piecewise differentiable, say piecewise affine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such bijection in general. For example, let

- $P=(-1,0)$, $Q=(1,0)$, and $R=(0,1)$
- $P'=P$, $Q'=Q$, and $R'=(0,2)$

Then $M=\sqrt{5/2}$ and $m=1$.

The line segment from $R$ to $(0,0)$  has length $1$. It must be mapped by $f$ to some curve connecting $R'$ to the $x$-axis. Any such curve has length at least $2$; therefore,
$$
\sup_{x\in PQR}\sup_{\|v\|=1}\|dfv\|\ge 2>M
$$

---

Replacing $R$ and $R'$ by $(0,\epsilon)$ and $(0,\sqrt{\epsilon})$, you will see that it's not even possible to have 
$$
\sup_{x\in PQR}\sup_{\|v\|=1}\|dfv\|\le CM
$$
with a universal $C$. Indeed, as $\epsilon\to 0$, the required norm of $df$ tends to infinity, while $M$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Okay, I was actually thinking of something else (namely, bounding $\|df\|-1$ by $C(M-1)$.) I deleted that part.

Comment: Updated with a correct example.